# How to add field to this form

Tags: magento2, forms

I have this file:

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Form/Account.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

namespace Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form;

use Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;

/**
 * Create order account form
 *
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Account extends AbstractForm
{
    /**
     * Metadata form factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\FormFactory
     */
    protected $_metadataFormFactory;

    /**
     * Customer repository
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $customerRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter
     */
    protected $_extensibleDataObjectConverter;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote $sessionQuote
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create $orderCreate
     * @param PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Reflection\DataObjectProcessor $dataObjectProcessor
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\FormFactory $metadataFormFactory
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
     * @param ExtensibleDataObjectConverter $extensibleDataObjectConverter
     * @param array $data
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote $sessionQuote,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create $orderCreate,
        PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Reflection\DataObjectProcessor $dataObjectProcessor,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\FormFactory $metadataFormFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter $extensibleDataObjectConverter,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_metadataFormFactory = $metadataFormFactory;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->_extensibleDataObjectConverter = $extensibleDataObjectConverter;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $sessionQuote,
            $orderCreate,
            $priceCurrency,
            $formFactory,
            $dataObjectProcessor,
            $data
        );
    }

    /**
     * Return Header CSS Class
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHeaderCssClass()
    {
        return 'head-account';
    }

    /**
     * Return header text
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        return __('Account Information');
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Form and add elements to form
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\Form $customerForm */
        $customerForm = $this->_metadataFormFactory->create('customer', 'adminhtml_checkout');

        // prepare customer attributes to show
        $attributes = [];

        // add system required attributes
        foreach ($customerForm->getSystemAttributes() as $attribute) {
            if ($attribute->isRequired()) {
                $attributes[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute;
            }
        }

        if ($this->getQuote()->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
            unset($attributes['group_id']);
        }

        // add user defined attributes
        foreach ($customerForm->getUserAttributes() as $attribute) {
            $attributes[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute;
        }

        $fieldset = $this->_form->addFieldset('main', []);

        $this->_addAttributesToForm($attributes, $fieldset);

        $this->_form->addFieldNameSuffix('order[account]');
        $this->_form->setValues($this->getFormValues());

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add additional data to form element
     *
     * @param AbstractElement $element
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _addAdditionalFormElementData(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        switch ($element->getId()) {
            case 'email':
                $element->setRequired(0);
                $element->setClass('validate-email admin__control-text');
                break;
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Return Form Elements values
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFormValues()
    {
        try {
            $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($this->getCustomerId());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            /** If customer does not exist do nothing. */
        }
        $data = isset($customer) ? $this->_extensibleDataObjectConverter->toFlatArray($customer, [], '\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface') : [];
        foreach ($this->getQuote()->getData() as $key => $value) {
            if (strpos($key, 'customer_') === 0) {
                $data[substr($key, 9)] = $value;
            }
        }

        if ($this->getQuote()->getCustomerEmail()) {
            $data['email'] = $this->getQuote()->getCustomerEmail();
        }

        return $data;
    }
}
```

which is generating this form which is displayed when you edit an order in adminhtml:

[image]

I have a custom attribute "mitgliedsnummer" which I added via a module and it's InstallData.php and which I want to add to the form.

This is the InstallData.php:

```
<?php
namespace UV\Mitgliedsnummer\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }


    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'mitgliedsnummer', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Mitgliedsnummer',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'position' =>999,
            'system' => 0,
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'mitgliedsnummer')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create'],//you can use other forms also ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address']
        ]);

        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

How do I do that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: what type of attribute is it ? customer, product etc

Comment: It is a customer attribute.

Comment: have you added customer attribute through some module ? and where do you want to show it in admin side or frontend side secondly how have you created this attribute using some module / extension ? could you please update your question that what, where and how you are trying to implement it. this will be lot easier for community member to help you out.

Comment: I created it using a module and the modules InstallData.php. It should be shown in adminhtml when I edit an ordner. I also edited the question. Thanks so far!

Comment: could you update your question with module's setup/installData.php file ?

Comment: I have done that :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable this attribute to admin checkout form by  adding another value index to 
'adminhtml_checkout'  at used_in_forms

So,

```
'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create']
```

**to**

```
 'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create' ,'adminhtml_checkout']
```